# In which table can I find the parameters of an uncommitted transaction in postgres

Tags: postgresql

If I start a transaction in a Postgres database
I can find it in the table  pg_stat_activity.
To retrieve the uncommitted transaction I use the following query:

```
from pg_stat_activity
where (state = 'idle in transaction')
  and xact_start is not null
```

This gives something like this:

```
datid            | 16397
datname          | msmith
pid              | 39437
leader_pid       | 
usesysid         | 16396
usename          | msmith
application_name | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
client_addr      | 127.0.0.1
client_hostname  | 
client_port      | 58411
backend_start    | 2021-11-24 09:07:06.571559+01
xact_start       | 2021-11-24 09:07:22.584942+01
query_start      | 2021-11-24 09:07:31.82002+01
state_change     | 2021-11-24 09:07:31.820198+01
wait_event_type  | Client
wait_event       | ClientRead
state            | idle in transaction
backend_xid      | 3446
backend_xmin     | 
query            | update students set address_id=$1, age=$2, first_name=$3, last_name=$4 where student_id=$5
backend_type     | client backend
```

In which table can I find the parameters for the prepared statement (update students set address_id=$1, age=$2, first_name=$3, last_name=$4 where student_id=$5)?

Answer (score 2):

That is not stored anywhere, and you cannot get it.

The only thing you can do is to set `log_min_duration_statement = 0`, so that all statements are logged upon completion. That will also log the parameter values, but depending on the workload, it can generate a *lot* of log entries.

Comment: But when is the data(parameters) being transmitted to the database server?
Is this done when the transaction is being committed?

Comment: No, they have already been transmitted when the statement was executed, and after that, the database forgot them.

Comment: So if I get it right a prepared statement was made by the client in a transaction and can be found in the table 'idle in transaction'.
This statement was executed by the client and retrieved by the server before the transaction was committed.

Comment: No, no, no. The steps are: 1. client sends a `PREPARE` message to server, server prepares statement. 2. client starts a transaction (can also happen before 1.) 3. client sends a `BIND` message to server that includes the parameters 4. client sends an `EXECUTE` message to the server, server executes the statement and sends the results to the client. Now the server is waiting for the next statement. It does not have the parameters any more.